# Is there a way to save gpflow2 models and restore in a different session?

Tags: tensorflow2.0, gpflow

In gpflow1 I was able to do:

```
saver = gpflow.saver.Saver()
saver.save(filename, model)
```

and then restore the model with

```
with tf.Graph().as_default() as graph, tf.Session().as_default():
    model_copy = saver.load(filename)
```

I saw that there is a way to checkpoint models in gpflow2, but it is not clear to me how I would restore a checkpoint in another session.

Any input would be appreciated.

Comment: This is a known issue (https://github.com/GPflow/GPflow/issues/1127) which will be fixed before properly releasing the 2.0 version.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Save the model in gpflow 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61752016/save-the-model-in-gpflow-2)